# Ubuntu 14.10 Bluetooth Arc touch mouse

Tags: 14.10, mouse, bluetooth

I'm having a little problem using my Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse. I'm able to see the mouse in the Bluetooth manager but unfortunately not to pair it and when I'm taking a look into the syslog I find the following:

```
Apr  9 14:12:00 thor bluetoothd[720]: No GATT server found in C4:85:08:07:50:D9
Apr  9 14:12:00 thor bluetoothd[720]: No GATT server found in C4:85:08:07:50:D9
Apr  9 14:12:00 thor bluetoothd[720]: Attribute server attach failure!
Apr  9 14:12:01 thor bluetoothd[720]: Unknown Management opcode 25 (index 0)
Apr  9 14:12:01 thor bluetoothd[720]: Could not update GATT services
Apr  9 14:12:07 thor bluetoothd[720]: Unknown command complete for opcode 37
```

any ideas? I also tried to configure the device via the command line but hcitool scan didn't even manage to find the device.

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards,

Johannes

Comment: possible dupplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/574268/microsoft-arc-touch-mouse-doesnt-working-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: indeed I was mistaken believing 14.10 shipped with bluez 5.

Comment: Can I mark it as duplicate then? The duplicate's answer solved your issue?

Comment: The command is `hctool scan` not `hcitool scan`